# jQuery ajax throwing error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i need to send a request to my controler, but ajax throwing and error. I can't seem to figure out why. Here is the code

HTTPS is before defined constant, which i cannot write here!

```
        $("input").on("click", function(){
         var elem = $(this).attr("id");
         var execute;

         if( $(elem).prop('checked') == true ){
             execute = '+';
         } else {
             execute = '-';
         }
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',       
                url: HTTPS+'/path/to/controller/ctlAccess.php?do='+execute,
                data: {id:elem},
                success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                error: function(){
                            console.log("An error occurred: " + status + "nError: " + error); //AND ERROR: An error occurred: [object Object]nError: error
                        }
            });
        });
    });
```

And here is the controller:

```
    $SysData = new SysTables;

if ($_GET["do"] == "-") {
    $userId = preg_match('/[0-9]*(?=p)/', $_POST['id']);
    $pageId = preg_match('/(?<=p)[0-9]*/', $_POST['id']);
    $result = $SysData->deleteAccess($userId, $pageId);

$data = "ACCESS FOR ". $_POST['id']." DELETED";
    echo $data;
}
```

I think that requests do not even get to controler! I don't actually know hwere is the error. But path to file is right, and part where elem gets ir value works too, so i dont get where is the error!? Help please, thx

Comment: What is `HTTPS`? You're also sending a `POST` request

Comment: Show PHP errors and maybe `$SysData = new SysTables;` should be  `$SysData = new SysTables();?` Not sure if you can have without or not.

Comment: It might help if you actually set up your `error` function correctly and output more than a curse word; there are arguments that are passed to that function that provide you with useful information, make use of them.

Comment: If the request is never making it to your controller as you suspect, then the path is most likely NOT correct. Use firebug (or your web browser dev tools of choice) to see if the request is 404'ing

Comment: HTTPS is DEFINES CONSTANT which is in other part of code! And how can i set up this error function correcty? ADDED ERROR

Comment: Adding to @JasonFingar comment: Go to the Dev Tools of your browser and locate the Network tab. Once you are viewing the Network tab then refresh your webpage and look for a request to the URL you specified.

Comment: Have you try to echoed `HTTPS+'/path/to/controller/ctlAccess.php'` and access this page directly in a browser?

Comment: Okey, sorry from my part, and thank you for you answers! My fellow programmer, which is working more on controller and config part changed this HTTPS constant which was this hous about! Page forcess all requests go throu https and www and my friend took out the www part rom constant, and it broke. Now its ok, THX FOR YOUR TIME!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably specify the expected `dataType` in your AJAX call like this:

```
dataType: 'HTML'
```

I would also recommend switching to ALL POST data

So here is the whole AJAX thing (change your controller on the back-end to use `$_POST['do']`):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',       
    url: HTTPS+'/path/to/controller/ctlAccess.php',
    data: {
               'id':elem,
               'do':execute // do might be a reserved word so just encase it in quotes to force it as a string
          },
    dataType: 'HTML',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    }
});
```

I would like to know what `HTTPS` is exactly. As long as your not trying to make a cross-domain request then you honestly shouldn't need it.

And if you are trying to make a cross-domain request then that is a separate beast on it's own.

Comment: Same error. The thing is that it work just fine on other page and other tool! Which uses same HTTPS constant, and this constant is set at header, which is on all pages!

Comment: If you do `alert(HTTPS+'/path/to/controller/ctlAccess.php');` one line before the AJAX call then do you get the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You're appending the "execute" value at the end of the URL. As "execute" is a plus sign this will be translated to a single space and possibly be discarded by jQuery as an invalid URL.
You might try to make the content of "execute" something more readable.

You might also want to slightly modify your error handler, try this:

```
error: function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: Added console.log("An error occurred: " + status + "nError: " + error);
AND ERROR:
An error occurred: [object Object]nError: error

Ok ill try that